# Why is the for loop with a conditional not iterating all the way to the end of the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement

I am writing a function to change the letters in a string (to camelCase) and the dashes and underscores are used as markers for the end of a word. I want to know why my for loop is stopping before it reaches the end of the array, especially since the conditional code isn't being used.

I've tried console logging my tmp array and it has what I want in it (the '_' or '-'). But the code seems to mess up after the conditional so I'm thinking it has something to do with that.

```
for (let letter of arr) {
  arr.pop(letter)
  if (letter === '-' || letter === '_') {
    let tmp = []
    tmp.push(letter)
    console.log(tmp)
  } else {
    camelArr.push(letter)
    console.log(camelArr)
  }
}
```

Comment: `arr.pop()` - You're removing items from the array as you iterate through it.

Comment: ```pop()``` removes the item and therefore the length is reduced. This would also be the case if you used some other method to remove a different item. You don't need to ```pop()/push()```

Comment: you should not modify the collection while iterating on it using loops, instead use the functions like `filter`, `map` etc

Comment: `arr.pop(letter)` makes no sense

Comment: Thank you all that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Like pointed out you modify the array as you loop.

Something like a camelCase function might make sense using `Array.reduce`.

Eg.

```js
const camelCase = str =>
  [...str].reduce((a, v) => {
      if (['_', '-'].includes(v)) a.firstLet = true;
      else {
        a.str += a.firstLet ? v.toUpperCase() : v.toLowerCase()
        a.firstLet = false;
      }
      return a;
    }, {str: '', firstLet: false}).str;
  
console.log(camelCase('this_is-a-Test'));
console.log(camelCase('one-two-three-four'));
```

Answer (score -1):

you may have to be more careful about 
arr.pop(letter)

The pop() method removes the last element of an array
: for every loop you are poping up last item in array..

try removing value @ specified index..

Comment: this isn't a real answer